# Issue with DST transition - reads day d entry and persists as (undesirably) day d-1

Tags: java, postgresql, date, jboss, pst

**Summary**
Reading a **one day after DST** entry and changing non-date field also changes the date field to minus 1 day (read Feb 22 persisted as Feb 21)

**Background**
postgres 9.2.7
jboss 4.2.3
centos
DST final date: Feb 22 2015 (At feb 22 00:00 we back to feb 21 23:00)

```
Foo
+--------------------------------------+                 
| id     | eventDate(date)|    name    |                           
+-------------------------+------------|                           
| 1      | 2015-02-22     |  Iorek     |                           
| 2      | 2015-02-22     |  Lyra      |                           
| 3      | 2015-02-22     |  Stanis    |                           
| 4      | 2015-02-22     |  Asriel    |                           
| 5      | 2015-02-23     |  Will      |                           
+--------------------------------------+
```

Foo.java (Pojo)
java.util.Date for eventDate

**Problem Scenario**

Using javaweb application: Loading an **Foo** object using HQL with id 1, for example, changing **only** the name from **Iorek** to **Compass** and persisting it, will also change the **eventDate** to -1 day. New table will look like below:

```
Foo after change
+--------------------------------------+                 
| id     | eventDate(date)|    name    |                           
+-------------------------+------------|                           
| 1      | 2015-02-21     |  Compass   |                           
| 2      | 2015-02-22     |  Lyra      |                           
| 3      | 2015-02-22     |  Stanis    |                           
| 4      | 2015-02-22     |  Asriel    |                           
| 5      | 2015-02-22     |  Will      |                           
+--------------------------------------+
```

If I name change an id 5 entry for example nothing happens with the eventDate. It only happens with entries in day 2015-02-22 (transition from DST to Normal)

**Attempts to reproduce**

This scenario only happens in production environment and was not confirmed in development.

Pointing development java to production database (read-only access) I could confirm that the timestamp is read properly and date is read as 2015-02-22 (unable to test write of a changed entry at day 22)

Comment: This is a problem with the alethiometer getting clogged up with dust {;-P

Comment: Do you get the same behaviour when you UPDATE a record with psql or pgAdmin III? If so, then it must be a PostgreSQL issue, if not it is a Java or Hibernate issue.

Comment: We are unable to hot change production entries. =(